# what is the time complexity of .equals in java for 2 strings?

Tags: java, string, big-o

I was wondering what the time complexity (big O) of the .equals operator in Java was for two strings.

Basically, if I did stringOne.equals(stringTwo) how well does this perform?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you think? How do you think is that equality check implemented?

Comment: If both `String`s have been `intern`ed, it can be done in constant time.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers here are over-simplistic.

In general, proving that two different Strings are equal is `O(n)` because you *may* have to compare each character.

However this is only a worst-case: there are many shortcuts that mean that the `equals()` method can perform much better than this in the average / typical cases:

- It's `O(1)` if the Strings are identical: they are the same object so equal by definition so the result is true
- It's `O(1)` if you are able to check pre-computed hashcodes, which can prove that two Strings are *not equal* (obviously, it can't help prove that two Strings are equals because many Strings hash to the same hashcode).
- It's `O(1)` if the Strings are of different lengths (they can't possibly be equal, so the result is false)
- You only need to detect one different character to prove that Strings are not equal. So for *randomly distributed* Strings, it is actually average `O(1)` time to compare two Strings. If your Strings aren't completely random, then the result may be anywhere between `O(1)` and `O(n)` depending on the data distribution.

As you can see, the exact performance **depends on the distribution of the data**.

Apart from that: this is **implementation dependent** so exact performance characteristics will depend on the version of Java used. However, to my knowledge, all the current main Java implementations do the optimisations listed above so you can expect `equals()` performance on Strings to be pretty fast.

A final trick: If you use **String interning** then all Strings that are equal will be mapped to the same object instance. Then you can use the extremely fast `==` check for object identity in place of `equals()`, which is guaranteed to be `O(1)`. This approach has downsides (you may need to intern a lot of Strings, causing memory issues, and you need to strictly remember to intern any Strings that you plan to use with this scheme) but it is extremely useful in some situations.

Comment: The other downside of interning is that you have to **remember** to intern every string that will be compared.  If one single un-interned string gets compared using `==` then your code may break.  This makes your application fragile.

Comment: You could also mention the (hypothetical) optimizations that depend on a String object's (implementation specific) caching of hashcodes.

Comment: Hash collision called. > It's O(1) if you are able to check pre-computed hashcodes, which can prove that two Strings are not equal (obviously, it can't help prove that two Strings are equals because many Strings hash to the same hashcode).

Comment: Hell, if the application's sole goal is to compare a well defined pool of string, interning can be a huge deal. Maybe I should get used to check my goals twice before using a general-purpose algorithm.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Same reason as sgupta.

Answer (score 14):

Worst case is O(n), unless the two strings are the same object in which case it's O(1).

(Although in this case n refers to the number of matching characters in the two strings starting from the first character, not the total length of the string).

Comment: True, I forgot about object identity.

Comment: OpenJDK at least checks that the `String`s have the same length before comparing the characters.

Comment: This Answer is **misleading**.  The conventional N in a scaling question is the length / size of the data structure ...

Answer (score 1):

To add to the excellent answers , we can see it looking at the code :

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) { // O(1)
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) //O(1)  {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) { // O(1)
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {  // O(n)
                if (v1[i] != v2[i]) //O(1)
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Best case : O(1)

Worst case : O(n)