# How to find big O of this function

Tags: java, loops, big-o, concept

So I have this function that iterates through an 8x8 multidimensional array in Java. I am trying to understand the big O of this function in findTheBoss(). It searches a static 8x8 grid for a given string. I really want to understand how to find the Big O of a basic function such as this. I think this is O(n^2) but I'm not sure. Please help me to understand how to find the equation for this function.

```
public static void FindTheBoss(String[][] bossGrid, String bossName){

    for(int i=0; i < bossGrid.length; i++)
    {               
        //Iterate through each row?

        for(int j=0; j < bossGrid[i].length; j++)
        {

            if(bossGrid[i][j].equals(bossName))
            {

                System.out.println("Found '" + bossName + "' at position "+ i + "," + j);
                break;
            }
        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: Understand how many times `outer loop` runs and for each `outer loop iteration`, understand how many times `inner loop` runs. BTW your answer is correct but I will leave up to you to analyze **why**?

Comment: The outer loop runs however long n is right, so it would be n for the outer. But the inner one runs however many total items are inside the multidimensional array. Would that be n^2? what if it weren't a perfect square, how would it be n^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. But be careful, big O notation can be tricky, even if it is not that complicated when you are methodic.

Let's summarize what your code does : you receive a 2D array of size NxN and a String of length S and try to find the string (one or several times) in your matrix. Even if you *break* the loop some times, just assume that it doesn't happen that much. You are then just iterating over elements of this matrix and comparing two strings for each element.

Basically, if you say that this algorithm is O(N^2), it might be fair enough. But be careful to know what N is. If your grid can have N rows and M columns, you would say that the algorithm is O(N*M), which is O(N^2) only in the square case (this is a very common mistake).

However, I wouldn't say that this algorithm is O(N^2), but rather **O(S*N^2)**. Indeed, what does *equals* do ? Comparison character by character until a character differs. In the case N is small but the string is insanely long, you see that it is important to take that into account.

---

**Note** : you can read this [interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552285/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-equals-in-java-for-2-strings) about the complexity of String.equals(). It can obviously be faster than O(S) if you compare precomputed length or hash codes, but these are internal optimization and the worst case is still O(S).

Comment: I see. Thank you, I really am fascinated in being able to compute the functionality of my algorithm. I didn't account for the length of strings. You're right that would hinder the performance of the algorithm if some of the objects were a 200 character string.

Comment: You're welcome. There are generally two approaches to find the complexity. It is good to try both at the beginning. I come up to my solution by thinking about the concept : what does your program does ? The other solution is to check the code and think about the cost of loops and each line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for uni-dimensional array in this post is quite decent. https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/how-to-calculate-big-o.html

In this post he talks about two dimensional arrays: 
https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html
There is a coursera link in his explanation about big-O for two dimensional arrays.